# How can I get open() to skip bytes at the beginning of a binary file?

Tags: python

I would like to open time series data written as a binary file using Python 3.5.

Here is the script that I wrote so far:

```
filename = 'dummy.ats'
file = open(filename, 'rb')
```

The binary file starts with a header of 1024 bytes that I would like to skip. How can I modify my script to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Why not just `read` the appropriate number of bytes and discard the result, or `seek` to the start of the part you want to use?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I did not know about `seek()`: I will try using this method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `seek()` allows you to move the reading cursor where you want in your file (this cursor automatically moves forward when you read something).

It works like :

```
file.seek(how many positions you will move[,0 or 1 or 2])
```

> ( [] <- means optional)

- 0 (or `os.SEEK_SET`): means your reference point is the beginning of the file
- 1 (or `os.SEEK_CUR`): means your reference point is the current file position
- 2 (or `os.SEEK_END`): means your reference point is the end of the file

But you can omit it and it'll be 0

```
filename = 'dummy.ats'
file = open(filename, 'rb')
file.seek(2)
```

if you read from there, you'll read from the 2nd character

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Hearner! This solved my problem!